# Can I find the field that will be updated from a WorkflowRule

Tags: rest-api, workflow, tooling-api, sobjectfield

So I have two workflow rules that fire when an Opportunity is created/updated.  These two workflows set the same variable to either true/false depending on which criteria is met.  I'm looking at pulling in the two Workflows through the REST API and I can do that using

```
/services/data/v31.0/tooling/sobjects/WorkflowRule/{WorkFlowID}/
```

Now looking at the data I can see the actions associated with the Workflow Rule.

```
"actions": [
  {
    "name": "Action_Number_1",
    "type": "FieldUpdate"
  },
  {
    "name": "Action_Number_2",
    "type": "FieldUpdate"
  }
]
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to find a way to tell which field is being updated by the action.  I've tried numerous things. On the actual page for the action in Salesforce there is a row in column one that says "Field to Update: Opportunity: Field_Name", but I can't seem to pull in any relevant data with the REST API.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After querying for the WorkflowRule data type you should pull the WorkflowFieldUpdate type. It's available via tooling API and should bring you all required details. See the specs here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_workflowfieldupdate.htm

Comment: Thank you, I'm still working on connecting all the dots for how each object fits together, but the WorkflowFieldUpdate definitely got me what I needed in terms of which field is being updated.